# How do I control what parts of a python script run as root

Tags: python, linux, selenium, sudo

I'm writing a scraper for the dark web. One step involves creating a torrc file in /etc/tor/, which requires root access. To do this, I just run the python file  with sudo (i.e. 'sudo python filename.py').

However, I encountered an error with selenium:
`Running Firefox as root in a regular user's session is not supported`

I googled the error and found solutions on how to bypass that. I would rather not run it as root if possible.

How can I run the first part of the code as root, but not the second part?

Comment: Why do you need a _torrc file_?

Comment: Tor is slow so I run multiple tor clients concurrently, each with their own torrc file and port

Answer (score 0):

UNIX/Linux does not blithely turn root privilege on and off quite so easily.  You need to isolate the root portions in a separate script and run only those parts under root privilege.  This is also basic system security: grant *only* the needed privilege for any function.

Comment: Could you help me with a specific example? Let's say the specific part of my code is the creating of the torrc file. I could write a separate script that just writes this file with admin rights. Then I write the other script that doesn't have any code that needs admin rights. How do I run the second script without admin rights, and then have it call the first script with admin rights?

Comment: I'm confused -- I wrote a test script that doens't need root to do anything. I wrote a second that does. The first calls the second with `subprocess.call(['sudo', './venv/bin/python', 'test2.py'])`. I run the first script without sudo and everything runs fine. How come it was able to run the second script with sudo without me ever giving the password?

Comment: It depends on whether your script is given the right to invoke `sudo` privilege.  Apparently, it *does* have that right.  Even though the first script did not invoke `sudo` privilege, it inherited the potential from above.  I'm glad to see that you apparently figured out the coding details on your own -- that's much more in line with Stack Overflow practices.  If you hit a snag with the implementation, posting your attempt is *much* more likely to get a useful response.

Answer (score 0):

I’m not familiar with Tor, but you can try to relax the rights on the tor file.

Running something similar to **chmod +x /etc/tor/your_file** that will allow Firefox to use the file even if not run as a privileged user.